# Problem with JFreeChart on Talend AMC Perspective

Tags: eclipse, jfreechart, talend

I'm getting this error message when

Talend Cloud Big Data

Version: 7.3.1

Build id: 20200219_1130

OS: Linux, v.5.4.0-58-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.30, WebKit 2.30.3

Java version: 1.8.0_275

tries to generate charts on AMC perspective.

[image]

it says :

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.

Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart

Any Solution to this problem ?

Thank you

Edit - Full Error log :

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 2 2021-01-05 17:17:08.774
> !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
> "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench". !STACK 0
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart    at
> org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(ChartFactory.java:1918)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.model.AMCChartGenerator.generateLineChartForManyJobs(AMCChartGenerator.java:217)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.model.AMCChartGenerator.generateChart(AMCChartGenerator.java:97)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.ui.composite.ExecTimeComposite.drawJobsChart(ExecTimeComposite.java:60)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.ui.composite.ExecTimeComposite.doGenerateChart(ExecTimeComposite.java:51)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.ui.composite.AbstractChartComposite$InnerChartComposite.doGenerateChart(AbstractChartComposite.java:152)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.ui.composite.AtomicChartComposite.generateChart(AtomicChartComposite.java:126)
> at
> org.talend.amc.charts.ui.composite.AbstractChartComposite$InnerSelectionBasedComposite.selectionChanged(AbstractChartComposite.java:130)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: I found this : 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 2 2021-01-05 17:17:08.774
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart
 at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(ChartFactory.java:1918)
 at org.talend.amc.charts.model.AMCChartGenerator.generateLineChartForManyJobs(AMCChartGenerator.java:217)
 at org.talend.amc.charts.model.AMCChartGenerator.generateChart(AMCChartGenerator.java:97)
...

Comment: [edit] your question and put the full entry from the log there, your comment does not include enough information

Comment: Is the `JFreeChart` jar in you class path?